# Find CPU usage for file operations

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio, fopen, cpu-usage

I'm using file operations fopen, fclose, fseek, etc., in my C program. I'd like to know if I'm consuming too much of CPU and based on that would like to go for optimization. But, I'm not sure on how to calculate CPU usage for every function (fopen, fclose, etc.,).

Even if there is no standard tool available, any kind of suggestion to calculate it would be useful.

The program can run in both Visual Studio environment as well as Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many compilers support the notion of "profiling" which can give you a breakdown of the time spent in each function.  For example, under gcc there are the options **-p** and **-pg**, which generate profiling information which can be analyzed with the separate programs **prof** and **gprof**.

Comment: Finding CPU usage for file operations is almost a contradiction in terms: While I/O operations do use a bit of CPU resources, that's usually dwarfed by the time spent in, or waiting for, the actual I/O device (hard drive, serial port, network, ...).

Comment: Further to what 500 said: Doing I/O efficiently involves some tradeoffs: you often want to expend some extra CPU doing what might look like "inefficient" extra buffering operations, in order to better amortize the fixed expenses of the underlying operating system and I/O subsystem, and the storage medium itself.  So if (hypothetically) profiling showed you were spending a lot of CPU time in `fread`, that wouldn't necessarily mean you shouldn't call `fread`, if the alternatives performed less well.

Comment: Also, it's going to be hard to profile the stdio calls well.  Much of the work is typically performed by internal functions with names like `_filbuf` that you don't call directly, and might not even recognize.  Also, `getc` and `putc` (and `getchar` and `putchar`) are typically macros, not functions, so profiling won't capture the time for them separately.  (You could use `fgetc` and `fputc` instead, which are guaranteed to be functions, meaning that you *could* profile them, but their performance is likely to be significantly worse, so you'd defeat your purpose.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use clock function as below and the function is in time.h

```
int main ()
{
 clock_t start_t, end_t, total_t;
 int i;

 start_t = clock();
 printf("Starting of the program, start_t = %ld\n", start_t);

 printf("Going to scan a big loop, start_t = %ld\n", start_t);
 for(i=0; i< 10000000; i++) {
 }
 end_t = clock();
 printf("End of the big loop, end_t = %ld\n", end_t);

 total_t = (double)(end_t - start_t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 printf("Total time taken by CPU: %f\n", total_t  );
 printf("Exiting of the program...\n");

 return(0);
 }
```